# check nearly equal against a substitution matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a maybe simple problem but do not find an easy and comprehensive way to do it.

I have a substitution matrix and I want to check if a specific (or almost equal) value is in my substation matrix. If I would search for the exact value, I could use `==` and get a matrix back. But how do I get a similar result with `all.equal` function to provide a specific precision.

```
a <- matrix(c(0.00000, -85.063997, -43.005813,
              85.06400, 0.000000, 42.058184,
              43.00581, -42.058184, 0.000000),3,byrow=TRUE)
85.06400 == a
all.equal(85, a)
```

I would love to just get the column and row index or names back.

Thanks for any help or hint.

Comment: `which(floor(a) == 85, arr.ind = TRUE)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some details (like whether you want to measure absolute or relative error), but `abs(x-y)<eps` is a start: then you can use `which(...,arr.ind=TRUE)` to get row/column indices.

```
a <- matrix(c(0.00000, -85.063997, -43.005813,
              85.06400, 0.000000, 42.058184,
              43.00581, -42.058184, 0.000000),3,byrow=TRUE)
target <- 85.06400
which(abs(a-target)<.Machine$double.eps,arr.ind=TRUE)
##      row col
## [1,]   2   1
```